# Tile Mill error MBTiles: "out of bounds geographic extent"

Tags: tilemill, mbtiles

I'm trying to make MBTiles using Tile Mill. The data source is a geotiff exported from ArcMap Desktop 10.5 from a map document in the Web Mercator WGS84 Coordinate Reference system. Tile Mill keeps giving me the following:

> Detected out of bounds geographic extent 
>   (-180,7409548.0421638,-462071.4434831566,85.051) for layer 'untitled'.
>   Please ensure that the SRS for this layer is correct. Its native 
>   extent is '-467352.53737867775,7409548.0421638,-462071.4434831566,7413358.049783817'

```
GDALinfo gives: Size is 3119, 2250
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (-467352.537378677749075,7413358.049783816561103)
Pixel Size = (1.693200992472309,-1.693336720007161)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=300
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=300
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -467352.537, 7413358.050) (  4d11'53.88"W, 55d15'51.97"N)
Lower Left  ( -467352.537, 7409548.042) (  4d11'53.88"W, 55d14'41.75"N)
Upper Right ( -462071.443, 7413358.050) (  4d 9' 3.09"W, 55d15'51.97"N)
Lower Right ( -462071.443, 7409548.042) (  4d 9' 3.09"W, 55d14'41.75"N)
Center      ( -464711.990, 7411453.046) (  4d10'28.48"W, 55d15'16.87"N)
Band 1 Block=3119x8 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=3119x8 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=3119x8 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Comment: I don't understand the error message. Why does it give a geographic extent with -180 and 85.051 plus two coords that match the latitude of the northern and southern edges of the geotiff? What does this mean? And what am I supposed to do about it? Is there something wrong with TileMill?